# ROS Answers SE migration: create package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i use roscreate-pkg to create a new package. But when i use roscd name of pacekage. I can't find out. But if i use roscd cpp. it's ok. anyone can help me????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226828/create-package/) by [duonggiaxxi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25801/duonggiaxxi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be one of two things:

1. ROS can't find the package on your path, in which case you need to run `rospack profile` to update and fix path issues
2. You have not sourced your workspace, in which case you need to add `source <path_to_your_workspace>/devel/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc` (then resource your .bashrc or reopen your terminal window)

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ErivaldoJunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/25727/erivaldojunior/) on 2016-02-16**:
I also believe that the workspace wasn't sourced.